# Client Authentication Tomcat - trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I know this question appears no stackoverflow a lot, and the exception is to do with a missing truststore - but here is my issue:

1. Using Apache Tomcat v7.0.56 as server on Windows with Java 8.0.71
2. modified tomcat/conf/server.xml to include SSL Connector with truststoreType="PKCS12", truststoreFile="conf/regtomcat.truststore" truststorePass="password"

I launch tomcat and I know it is reading this truststore file correctly as I originally did not have the file in pkcs12 format and tomcat reported an error on startup.  I also have tried breaking the file location just to see tomcat startup fail as it can not find the file.  So tomcat launches okay - it is reading the truststore which must mean it exists and can be read.

I load a p12 file into my browser certificate, and go to my application URL.  I then get the tomcat error:

```
handling exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: 
the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

Given that my trustore exists, and contains my certificate - what could the problem be?

I generated all certificates and truststores using keytool.  The truststore was created using the command

```
keytool -importcert -alias regClient -storetype PKCS12 -keystore regtomcat.truststore -file regClient.cer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay - the problem was the certificate was created using JDK 1.8 and the tomcat was running with JRE 1.7 - for whatever reason this caused an issue, so the fix was to use JRE 1.8 and now everything works okay.

Answer (score 3):

One probable reason might be that if we use same .jks file as a keystore and as a truststore, then the server start up is failing with following error : java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty.
Keystore is to store the ServerCerts and TrustStore is to store the CA certs. On adding at least one CA certificate in the .jks, above issue will be resolved.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the CA to the jks and now I could even use **a same jks file as keystore and truststore without error**. The interesting fact is that the old jks file without CA was working on tomcat 8.0, But after switching to tomcat 9.0.56, The CA requirement in the jks has arose. (Albeit, the tomcat is running as a docker container based on Amazon Corretto)

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue. My keystore only had private key pair of the website. Imported the public certificates from the key pair all the way down to the root and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue. The cause was far more basic: the .jks file *must* be readable for the account under which tomcat service runs. Though we have it as a systemctl service (hence started/stopped from root) the account was tomcat, so a simple chown tomcat:tomcat for the .jks store did the job!

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was I was passing null to the keyword as password wherein the password was `changeit`

> ks.load(fis, "changeit".toCharArray());